# Basketball Game Phaser JS

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm making a basketball game and the shooting doesn't seem to be working. I have spent a very long time on this and I'm almost at my deadline so I need a little bit of help.

If anyone could help me that would be very appreciated.

Here's the code of the game.

It's in the Phaser CE Framework, and this is the main JS file.

```
// To-Do
// Fix player movement

let r = document.querySelector(':root');
let rs = getComputedStyle(r);
viewHeight = rs.getPropertyValue('--fh');
viewWidth = rs.getPropertyValue('--fw');


let game = new Phaser.Game(1000, 1000, Phaser.CANVAS, 'my-game', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });


let x0, y0, x1, y1, vX, vY, g;
let dX, dY, t, vX0;
let xNow, yNow;

// declare other global variables (for sprites, etc.)
let allowMovement = true;

let arrowKey;
// let shootKey;
let player;
let player1;
let player2;

let hoop;

let groundnewSpriteplayer;
let ball; 

let playerCount = 2;
let playerList = {};

let keyW;
let keyA;
let keyD;
 
let keyI;
let keyJ;
let keyL;
 
let KeyT;
let keyF;
let keyH;




let score = {
    player1: {
        score: 0
    },
    player2: {
        score: 0
    }
}


// preload game assets - runs one time when webpage first loads
function preload() {
    game.load.image('player', 'assets/images/real person.png');
    game.load.image('player', 'assets/images/player_temp.png');
    game.load.image('ground', 'assets/images/court_temp.png');
    game.load.image('cursorPosition', 'assets/images/bigball.png');
    game.load.image('ball', 'assets/images/Ball.png');
    game.load.image('hoop', 'assets/images/Hoop.png');     
    game.load.image('scoreboard', 'assets/images/scoreboard.png');
    game.load.image('stands', 'assets/images/Stands.png');
    game.load.image('ref', 'assets/images/ref.png');
    game.load.image('background', 'assets/images/Background.png');
    game.load.image('streetcourt', 'assets/images/streetcourt.png');
    game.load.audio('dribbling', 'assests/sounds/dribbling.wav');
    game.load.audio('whistle' , 'assets/sounds/whistle.wav');
    game.load.image('streethoop', 'assets/image/streethoop.png');
    game.load.image('waving', 'assets/images/standsanimation.png');
    game.load.image('0', 'assets/images/number/0.png');
    game.load.image('1', 'assets/images/number/1.png');
    game.load.image('2', 'assets/images/number/2.png');
    game.load.image('3', 'assets/images/number/3.png');
    game.load.image('4', 'assets/images/number/4.png');
    game.load.image('5', 'assets/images/number/5.png');
    game.load.image('6', 'assets/images/number/6.png');
    game.load.image('7', 'assets/images/number/7.png');
    game.load.image('8', 'assets/images/number/8.png');
    game.load.image('9', 'assets/images/number/9.png');
    
    // Shorts and Jerseys
    
    game.load.image('heatS', 'assets/images/shorts/heat.png');
    game.load.image('heatJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/heat.png');
    game.load.image('bucksS', 'assets/images/shorts/bucks.png');
    game.load.image('bucksJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/bucks.png');
    game.load.image('mavsS', 'assets/images/shorts/mavs.png');
    game.load.image('mavsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/mavs.png');
    game.load.image('grizzliesS', 'assets/images/shorts/grizzlies.png');
    game.load.image('grizzliesJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/grizzlies.png');
    game.load.image('clippersS', 'assets/images/shorts/clippers.png');
    game.load.image('clippersJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/clippers.png');
    game.load.image('warriorsS', 'assets/images/shorts/warriors.png');
    game.load.image('warriorsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/warriors.png');
    game.load.image('lakersS', 'assets/images/shorts/lakers.png');
    game.load.image('lakersJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/lakers.png');
    game.load.image('cavsS', 'assets/images/shorts/cavs.png');
    game.load.image('cavsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/cavs.png');
    game.load.image('bullsS', 'assets/images/shorts/bulls.png');
    game.load.image('bullsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/bulls.png');
    game.load.image('jazzS', 'assets/images/shorts/jazz.png');
    game.load.image('jazzJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/jazz.png');
    game.load.image('hornetsS', 'assets/images/shorts/hornets.png');
    game.load.image('hornetsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/hornets.png');
    game.load.image('blazersS', 'assets/images/shorts/blazers.png');
    game.load.image('blazersJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/blazers.png');
    game.load.image('knicksS', 'assets/images/shorts/knicks.png');
    game.load.image('knicksJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/knicks.png');
    game.load.image('celticsS', 'assets/images/shorts/celtics.png');
    game.load.image('celticsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/celtics.png');
    game.load.image('hawksS', 'assets/images/shorts/hawks.png');
    game.load.image('hawksJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/hawks.png');
    game.load.image('kingsS', 'assets/images/shorts/kings.png');
    game.load.image('kingsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/kings.png');
    game.load.image('magicS', 'assets/images/shorts/magic.png');
    game.load.image('magicJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/magic.png');
    game.load.image('pistonsS', 'assets/images/shorts/pistons.png');
    game.load.image('pistonsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/pistons.png');
    game.load.image('nuggetsS', 'assets/images/shorts/nuggets.png');
    game.load.image('nuggetsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/nuggets.png');
    game.load.image('raptorsS', 'assets/images/shorts/raptors.png');
    game.load.image('raptorsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/raptors.png');
    game.load.image('rocketsS', 'assets/images/shorts/rockets.png');
    game.load.image('rocketsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/rockets.png');
    game.load.image('sixersS', 'assets/images/shorts/sixers.png');
    game.load.image('sixersJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/sixers.png');
    game.load.image('spursS', 'assets/images/shorts/spurs.png');
    game.load.image('spursJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/spurs.png');
    game.load.image('sunsS', 'assets/images/shorts/suns.png');
    game.load.image('sunsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/suns.png');
    game.load.image('thunderS', 'assets/images/shorts/thunder.png');
    game.load.image('thunderJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/thunder.png');
    game.load.image('wolvesS', 'assets/images/shorts/wolves.png');
    game.load.image('wolvesJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/wolves.png');
    game.load.image('wizardsS', 'assets/images/shorts/wizards.png');
    game.load.image('wizardsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/wizards.png');
    game.load.image('pelicansS', 'assets/images/shorts/pelicans.png');
    game.load.image('pelicansJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/pelicans.png');
    game.load.image('netsS', 'assets/images/shorts/nets.png');
    game.load.image('netsJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/nets.png');
    game.load.image('pacersS', 'assets/images/shorts/pacers.png');
    game.load.image('pacersJ', 'assets/images/jerseys/pacers.png');

    //Shoes
    game.load.image('Green Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/Green Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Black_White Shoes', 'assests/imges/shoes/black , white Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Black Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/Black shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Blue Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/blue Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Bright_purple Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/bright purple Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Grey Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/Grey Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Lime_Green Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/Lime Green shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Orange Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/Orange Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Pink Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/Pink Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('purple_blue Shoes', 'assests/images/shoes/purple and blue Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Purple Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/Purple Shorts.png');
    game.load.image('Red Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/Red Shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Sky_Blue Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/SkyBlue shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Teal Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/Teal  shoes.png');
    game.load.image('White Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/White shoes.png');
    game.load.image('Yellow Shoes', 'assests/imaages/shoes/Yellow Shoes.png');
   
       

}

// create game world - runs one time after preload finishes
function create() {
    
    arrowKey = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    // shootKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.SPACEBAR);

    keyW = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.W);
    keyA = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.A);
    keyD = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.D);

    keyY = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.Y);
    keyG = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.G);
    keyJ = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.J);


    
    // background

    background = game.add.sprite(0,0, 'background');

    // make Ground
    ground = game.add.sprite(0,300, 'ground');

    // streetcourt = game.add.sprite(0,300, 'streetcourt', false);

    // Stands
    
    stands = new Sprite(0,95, 'stands', true);
    stands.animations.add('moving', [0, 1, ], 10, true);
    
    
    // stands.height = 30 * 7;
    // stands.width = 40 * 20;
    


    // Ref

    ref = new Sprite(300, 250, 'ref', true);
    // ref.height *= 2;
    // ref.width *= 2;



    // Scoreboard

    scoreboard = new Sprite(300, 0, 'scoreboard', true);
    // scoreboard.height = 50 * 3;
    // scoreboard.width = 75 * 3;
    console.log(scoreboard);

    // numbers 

    n1 = new Sprite(300,0, '1', false);
    n2 = new Sprite(300,0, '2', false);
    n3 = new Sprite(300,0, '3', false);
    n4 = new Sprite(300,0, '4', false);
    n5 = new Sprite(300,0, '5', false);
    n6 = new Sprite(300,0, '6', false);
    n7 = new Sprite(300,0, '7', false);
    n8 = new Sprite(300,0, '8', false);
    n9 = new Sprite(300,0, '9', false);
    n0 = new Sprite(300,0, '0', false);


    

    // Players

    player1 = new Player(100, 100, 'player');
    player2 = new Player(100, 100, 'player');

    player1.height *= 2.0;
    player1.width *= 1.5;

    player2.height *= 2.0;
    player2.width *= 1.5;

    playerList = {
        player1: player1,
        player2: player2,
    }


    player1.shootKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.F1);
    player2.shootKey = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.F10);
   

    // Ball
    
    ball = new Sprite(100, 300, 'ball', true);
    // ball.gravity = 0.3;
    ball.gravity = 0.1;
    ball.control = {
        controller: player1,
        inControl: true
    };
    ball.bounceVelocity = 5;
    // ball.scale = 1/2;
    // ball.width  = 8;
    // ball.height = 8;

    // console.log(ball)
    
    
    cursorPosition = game.add.sprite(800, 150, 'cursorPosition');
    cursorPosition.visible = false;
    // cursosrPosition.rotation = 16;

    testItem = game.add.sprite(760, 194, 'cursorPosition');
    testItem.width = 10;
    testItem.height = 20;
    testItem.Collision = true;
    testItem.visible = false;

    // break

    //Hoop

    streethoop = new Sprite(715, 115, 'streethoop', false);
    streethoop.height = 300;
    streethoop.width = 150;
    streethoop.visible = false;

    hoop = new Sprite(715, 115, 'hoop', true);
    hoop.height = 300;
    hoop.width = 150;
    hoop.visible = true;
    // console.log(`Hoop height: ${hoop.height}`);
   
}





// update game - runs repeatedly in loop after create finishes
function update() {

    // player1.height *= 1.002;
    // player1.width *= 1.002;
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= playerCount; i++) {
        let player = playerList['player' + i]; /* Establish player */
        gravity(player);
        applyFriction(player);
        collision(player);
        keyboardInput(player);
        
    }

    gravity(ball);

    // Movement

    movement(player1, arrowKey.right, arrowKey.left, arrowKey.up, false);
    movement(player2, keyD, keyA, keyW);
    // movement(player3, keyG, keyJ, keyY);
    //movement(player4, keyFOUR, keySIX, keyEIGHT);
   
    
    
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= playerCount; i++) {
        let player = playerList['player' + i];
        applyVelocity(player);
    }
    
    
    hoopCollision(ball, cursorPosition); // Fix this function so it doesn't extend below the hoop

    // keyboardInput();
    applyVelocity(ball);
    ballControl();
    ballCollision();
}


// Stands 
// stands.animations.play('moving');


// Helper Functions

function Key(key) {
    if (key == undefined) return;
    return game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.KeyCode.key);
}

function ballControl() {
    if (ball.control.inControl) {
        ball.x = ball.control.controller.x + ball.control.controller.width - (ball.width / 2);
        ball.y = ball.control.controller.y + ball.control.controller.height / 10;
        ball.velocityY = 0;
        ball.bounceVelocity = 5; 
    }
    if (ball.bounceVelocity < 0) {
        ball.bounceVelocity = 0;
        ball.velocityY = 0;
        ball.velocityX = 0;
    }
}

function keyboardInput(entity) {
    // if (entity.x > 512) {
    //     handleShooting(entity, 2, -6.2);
    // }

    handleShooting(entity);

    // console.log(`Y ${entity.y}`);
}

// function initializePositions() {
//     x0 = ball.x
//     y0 = ball.y
//     x1 = cursosrPosition.x - 10;
//     y1 = testItem.y;

//     vX = 5;
//     vY = 10;
//     g = ball.gravity

//     dX = x1 - x0;
//     dY = y1 - y0;
//     t = (2 * vY) / g;
//     vX0 = dX / t;
// }

// function updateShooting() {
//     let tNow = game.time.totalElapsedSeconds();
//     let dt = tNow - tStart;
// }

function handleShooting(entity) {
    if (entity.shootKey.isDown && ball.control.inControl && ball.control.controller == entity) {
        
        ball.dy += ball.gravity;
        ball.dx = (cursorPosition.x - ball.x);
    
        ballNorm = sqrt(ball.dx^2 + ball.dy^2);
        ball.dx /= ballNorm;
    
    
        ball.x += ball.dx;
        ball.y += ball.dy



    }
}


function Player(x, y, key) {
    let newPlayer = new Sprite(x, y, key, true);
    newPlayer.x = x;
    newPlayer.y = y;
    newPlayer.velocityX = 0;
    newPlayer.velocityY = 0;
    newPlayer.movementSpeed = 4;
    newPlayer.gravity = 1;
    newPlayer.isTouchingGround = false;
    newPlayer.jumpVelocity = 20;

    return newPlayer;
}

function Sprite(x, y, key, visible) {
    let newSprite = game.add.sprite(x, y, key);
    if (!visible) newSprite.visible = false;
    newSprite.isTouching = function(collider) {
        collider.left = collider.x;
        collider.right = collider.x + collider.width;
        collider.up = collider.y;
        collider.down = collider.y + collider.height;

        newSprite.left = newSprite.x;
        newSprite.right = newSprite.x + newSprite.width;
        newSprite.up = newSprite.y;
        newSprite.down = newSprite.y + newSprite.height;

        let touchingRight = false;
        let touchingLeft = false;
        let touchingUp = false;
        let touchingDown = false;

        let touching = false;

        if (newSprite.right > collider.left) touchingRight = true;
        if (newSprite.left < collider.right) touchingLeft = true;

        if (newSprite.up < collider.down) touchingUp = true;
        if (newSprite.down > collider.up) touchingDown = true;

        if (touchingRight && touchingLeft && touchingUp && touchingDown) touching = true;
        return touching;
    }

    return newSprite;
}

function applyVelocity(entity) {
    if (entity.velocityX == null) return;
    entity.y += entity.velocityY;
    entity.x += entity.velocityX;
    // if (entity = player1) {
    //     console.log(`AppVelocityVelocityX: ${entity.velocityX}`);
    //     console.log(`AppVelocityEntityX ${entity.x}`);
    // }
}

function gravity(entity) {
    // Applies gravity to the given entity, usually the player or an enemy
    if (entity.gravity == null) return;
    entity.velocityY += entity.gravity;
}

function collision(entity) {
    if (ground.y + ground.height / 2 < entity.y + entity.height + entity.velocityY) {
        entity.velocityY = 0;
        entity.isTouchingGround = true;
        entity.y = ground.y + ground.height / 2 - entity.height;
    }
    if(ball.isTouching(entity) && !ball.control.inControl) {
        ball.control.inControl = true;
        ball.control.controller = entity; 
    }
}

function checkWallCollision(entity, right, left, up) {
    if (entity.x <= 0) {
        if (left.isDown) {
            entity.velocityX = 0;
        }
    }
    if (entity.x >= game.width - entity.width) {
        if (right.isDown) {
            entity.velocityX = 0;
        }
    }
    ballCollision();
}

function ballCollision() {
    if (ball.y >= ground.y + ground.height / 2 - ball.height) {
        jump(ball, ball.bounceVelocity, true);
        ball.bounceVelocity -= 1;
        ball.y = ball.y = ground.y + ground.height / 2 - ball.height
        if (ball.bounceVelocity <= 0) ball.y = ball.y = ground.y + ground.height / 2 - ball.height
    }
}



function movement(entity, right, left, up, log) {
    entity.moveRight = false;
    entity.moveLeft = false;
    entity.tryJump = false;

    if (right.isDown) entity.moveRight = true;
    if (left.isDown) entity.moveLeft = true;
    if (up.isDown) entity.tryJump = true;

    if (entity.moveRight) entity.velocityX += entity.movementSpeed;
    if (entity.moveLeft) entity.velocityX -= entity.movementSpeed;

    if (entity.tryJump) jump(entity, entity.jumpVelocity, false);

    if (log == undefined) log = false;
    if (log) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) console.log("");
        console.log(`Movement Speed: ${entity.movementSpeed}`);
        console.log(`velocityX: ${entity.velocityX}`);
        
    }

    checkWallCollision(entity, right, left, up);
}

function jump(entity, velocity, override) {
    if (!override) {
        if (!entity.isTouchingGround) return;
    }
    if (entity == undefined) return;
    if (velocity == undefined) return;

    entity.velocityY -= velocity;
    entity.isTouchingGround = false;
    return;
    
    
}

function applyFriction(entity) {
    if (entity.velocityX > 6) entity.velocityX =  6;
    if (entity.velocityX < 6) entity.velocityX = -6;
    entity.velocityX = 0;

    if (entity.velocityX > 0) entity.velocityX -= 1;
    if (entity.velocityX < 0) entity.velocityX += 1;

}


function moveTowardSolidEntity(entity, ground) {
    
}

function hoopCollision(entity, hoop) {
    if (entity.x + entity.width >= hoop.x) {
        if (entity.y + entity.height >= hoop.y) {
            if (entity.y <= hoop.y + hoop.height) {
                return entity.velocityX *= -1;
            }
        }

    }

     if (ball.x <= testItem.x + testItem.width) {
         if (ball.x + ball.width >= testItem.width) {
             return ball.velocityX *= -1;
        }
     }
    if (ball.x <= testItem.x + testItem.width) {
        if (ball.x + ball.width >= testItem.x) {
            if (ball.y + ball.height >= testItem.y) {
                if (ball.y<= testItem.y + testItem.width) {
                    return ball.velocityX *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

     if (ball.y + ball.height >= testItem.y) {
         if (ball.y<= testItem.y + testItem.width) {
             return ball.velocityX *= -1;
         }
     }

    if (entity.x + entity.width >= hoop.x) {
        if (entity.x <= hoop.x + hoop.width) {
            // If good on the x


            if (entity.y + entity.height >= hoop.y) {
                if (entity.y + entity.height >= hoop.y + 10) {
                    if (entity.y <= hoop.y - hoop.height) {
                        entity.velocityY *= -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function setScoreboardNumber(score) {
    
}
```

I tried to fix it and it did not work.

When you shoot nothing happens and I cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor error in your code, in the function `handleShooting` , the line

```
 ballNorm = sqrt(ball.dx^2 + ball.dy^2);
```

should be

```
 ballNorm = Math.sqrt(ball.dx^2 + ball.dy^2);
```

> **Tipp:** I recommend to check the browser console, if the phaser application, doesn't work as expected, errors cause the application to stop.

> **Tipp 2:** to get faster and better solution, I would recommend creating a demo application, with only the problematic code, this makes it easier for you to find the error and other the help you.

> **btw.:** If you have the option I would recommend switching to phaser 3 Version.